# Adding carousel to the page

Tags: html, css

The carousel isn't working as it supposed to work. I've checked the code several times but it seems I don't know why there's no transition between the photos

I've tried adding the carousel to my webpage but somehow only the active photo is being displayed. There is no transition in the photo-set.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="main-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="img/slide_01.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
      <!--carousel item-->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/slide_02.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/slide_03.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#main-slider" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#main-slider" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

The three photo set "slide_01.jpg" ,"slide_02.jpg","slide_01.jpg" should change on the click of the "carousel-control-next" button.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] - Also, please include a [mcve] to your question so that it's easier, faster to provide you with an accurate answer

Comment: Also, which version of jquery/bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I have added bootstrap though I've not shown it here. It 's just the snippet of my overall code which exceeds more than 150 lines. It's the latest version v4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included all the necessary libraries for the carousel to work.

If you are using Bootstrap v4.2 then you need the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I copied your HTML code and it works...

**See demo below**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h2>demo</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div id="main-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/400" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
      <!--carousel item-->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/400" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/400" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#main-slider" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#main-slider" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, man...a lot !!! But tell me this I too added the scripts directly from the bootstrap site but when I added yours, it seems to work, how come? These were the files I've added.

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: @Shinichi - I noticed what when I include the `integrity` and `crossorigin` attributes, the whole carousel fails as well.  I just removed them from my code (those are added for extra checks, the scripts work well without them)

Comment: @Shinichi also if my answer works for you, feel free to mark it as such